# Convert DateTime to another timezone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

How do I convert a `DateTime` from the local timezone returned by `DateTime.Now` to another timezone than Utc. On desktop we have the `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId()`, but it's not available on windows phone!

This java snippet shows roughtly what I want to do

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US); 
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
str = format.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible to do using the system libraries as there is no way to create `TimeZoneInfo` objects other than local and utc. They have also [sealed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) the class.

You can however use this simple library to enable conversion to non-local time zones.
https://nuget.org/packages/WinRTTimeZones

Use it like this:

```cs
using TimeZones;    

public void ConvertTime()
{
    // Get the time zone we want

    var tz = TimeZoneService.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
    var dt = new DateTime(1990, 7, 1, 12, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    // This time will be central time
    var local = tz.ConvertTime(dt);
}
```

When the `DateTime` is converted it is an easy exercise to format it as you want. I recommend to format the date in the local format (not the local timezone) to make easy for the user to understand the date.

Comment: i have added this nuget, but this is not working with "Any CPU" platform configuration. But it works fine for ARM and x86 platforms individually.

Comment: @KdSingh I'm bit personally developing the library, please contact the maintainers for the library regarding this issue

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
public String getNationTime(String Zone)
    {
        DateTime todayutc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        string todaydate = todayutc.ToShortDateString();
        string todaytime = todayutc.TimeOfDay.ToString().Split('.')[0];
        Zone = Zone.Replace("GMT", "");
        if (Zone.Length == 0)
            return todaytime;

        int zoneHour = int.Parse(Zone.Split(':')[0]);
        int zoneMin = int.Parse(Zone.Split(':')[1]);

        TimeSpan diff = new TimeSpan(zoneHour, zoneMin, 00);
        todayutc = todayutc.Add(diff);

        return todayutc.TimeOfDay.ToString().Split('.')[0];
    }
```