# Convert Local TimeZone to PST in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to Convert my Local TimeZone to PST in Windows Phone, do we have an API to do it? If not then what is the best practice here? Note the phone can be in any timezone based on where it is located in the world.

Comment: By "PST" do you actually mean "Pacific Time"? And do you really need to convert an arbitrary value in the local time zone, or just the *current* time in Pacific time? (If it's the latter, you can use DateTime.UtcNow to take the local time zone into consideration.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230393/convert-datetime-to-another-timezone

Comment: Hi @Jon Skeet Yes it is Pacific Time and i need current time in Pacific Time But how i can define destinationTimeZone in   TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime() method

Comment: @user3895718: Ah, you only need the current time? That definitely makes it easier. I'll edit my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean Pacific Time, you can use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project for this, assuming that `DateTime` works correctly in terms of the the local conversion.

```
// Initial conversion using BCL classes
DateTime local = ...;
DateTime utc = local.ToUniversalTime();

// The rest in Noda Time
Instant instant = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(utc);
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Los_Angeles"];
ZonedDateTime pacificTime = instant.InZone(zone);
```

From the `ZonedDateTime` you can get the `LocalDateTime`, or just keep it as a `ZonedDateTime`. (You can convert back to a `DateTime` as well, with `ToDateTimeUnspecified()`.)

You *can* ask Noda Time to do both parts of the conversion, but because the PCL version of `TimeZoneInfo` doesn't provide the `Id` property, we have to perform some heuristics to guess the time zone - using `DateTime` to do the first conversion may be a little more reliable (although it doesn't give you as much control over how to handle DST transitions).

If you only need the *current* time, you don't need the BCL types at all. You can go for Noda Time all the way:

```
// You'd normally inject this, so that you can test different scenarios. Noda Time
// provides a Testing package which includes a fake implementation of IClock.
// Use SystemClock.Instance for production use.
IClock clock = ...;
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Los_Angeles"];
ZonedDateTime pacificTime = clock.Now.InZone(zone);
```

In Noda Time 2.0, we're introducing `ZonedClock` which will make things slightly easier, too - you'll be able to create a `ZonedClock` for the Pacific time zone, and then ask it for the current `ZonedDateTime` or the current `LocalDateTime`.